# Objective C - Parse NSData

Tags: objective-c, parsing, nsdata

I have the following data inside an NSData object:

<00000000 6f2d840e 31504159 2e535953 2e444446 3031a51b 8801015f 2d02656e 9f110101 bf0c0cc5 0affff3f 00000003 ffff03>

I'm having issues parsing this data. This data contains information which is marked by tags

Tag 1 is from byte value 0x84 to 0xa5

Tag 2 is from byte value 0xa5 to 0x88

Tag 3 is from byte value 0x88 to 0x5f0x2d

Tag 4 is from byte value 0x5f0x2d to 0x9f0x11

How would I go about to get those values from the NSData object?

Regards,
EZFrag

Comment: @ETFrag what your exact need? I think it is better to convert it to NSString or some thing else as u required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed a nice solution, deciding to actually use the graymatter

```
-(int)getIndexOfSubDataInData:(NSData*)haystack forData:(NSData*)needle{
    int dataCounter = 0;
    NSRange dataRange = NSMakeRange(dataCounter, [needle length]);
    NSData* compareData = [haystack subdataWithRange:dataRange];

    while (![compareData isEqualToData:needle]) {

        dataCounter++;
        dataRange = NSMakeRange(dataCounter, [needle length]);
        compareData = [haystack subdataWithRange:dataRange];
    }

    return dataCounter;
}

-(NSData*)getSubDataInData:(NSData*)targetData fromTag:(NSData*)fromTag toTag:(NSData*)toTag{

    int startIndex = [self getIndexOfSubDataInData:targetData forData:fromTag] + [fromTag length];
    int endIndex = [self getIndexOfSubDataInData:targetData forData:toTag];
    int dataLength = endIndex - startIndex;

    NSRange dataRange = NSMakeRange(startIndex, dataLength);

    return [targetData subdataWithRange:dataRange];
}

//here is how I use the code
 NSData* langTagStart=[[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:"\x5F\x2D" length:2];
    NSData* langTagEnd=[[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:"\x9F\x11" length:2];

    NSData* languageData = [self getSubDataInData:[response bytes] fromTag:langTagStart toTag:langTagEnd];
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Regards,
EZFrag

Comment: I am converting NSString "Hello$World$" to NSData using NSUTF8StringEncoding and then want to find World from that data, so now i have used your above code and set lagTagStart's Bytes with "\x24"(as $ in Bytes have value 36,i.e. 24 in hexadecimal) and length 1, done similar thing for langTagEnd and passed to getSubDataInData as you have done, but it giving EXC_BAD_ACCESS in method getSubDataInData, Can You explain me why this thing is happening and what changes does i need to get String World out of that. Thanks is advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use `-[NSData bytes]` to get a pointer to the contents. Then use pointer arithmetic to iterate over the bytes until you find what you are looking for. Since you want to go byte by byte, you should probably cast the pointer returned by `bytes` to `uint8_t*`. Then, `pointer[0]` points to the first byte, `pointer[1]` to the second, and so on.

Comment: I tried that, but I received a compiler error when I tried to compare, pointer[0] with tag[0] eg. while(pointer[0] != tag[0]){ }

Comment: it complained about me comparing a void const against a void const

Comment: As Ole suggested, declare your pointers a `uint8_t*` so that when you dereference them, you get 8-bit unsigned integer values for each byte.